# High memory usage eloquent laravel in big queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

When I query with more than 1000 records, eloquent takes a lot of memory.
How can I solve it?!
For example, Imagine there is a `users` table with 10000+ records, and I want to run the below statement.

```
User::whereIsActive(1)->get()
    ->each(fn (User $user) => $user->notify())
```

Comment: do it with Command?

Comment: no difference, with the command, job, and HTTP I got the same result.

Comment: Just like pagination, do it in steps? Let's say, take 1000 first then notify then move to next 1000.

Comment: I think using chunks and the idea of lazy loading may help you in reducing memory overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `each()` directly in the Eloquent-Builder chain. By using `each()` Laravel automatically chunks the result by 1000.

```
User::whereIsActive(1)->each(fn (User $user) => $user->notify());
```

If you want lower chunks, add a 2nd argument to `each()`

```
User::whereIsActive(1)->each(fn (User $user) => $user->notify(), 100);
```

Your original code executes `get()` before `each()`. `get()` executes the database query and loads **all** results into memory and then uses Laravel collections' `each()` to chunk through them. Thats why it's using so much memory.